# Table markers for apa 6 class

Tags: apa6, endfloat

I am compiling a document using the `apa6` class. As expected in the manuscript mode, tables and figures are placed at the end of the document. However, unlike the normal `endfloat` behavior, no markers are placed in the main text.

I see from the `apa6` class, that it calls `endfloat` with the `nomarker` option. So two questions:

1. Is this standard for `apa6` to not have table references?
2. How can I tell `apa6` to place these references?

Thank you

Here is a minimal working example

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6} % man for manuscript format, jou for journal format, doc for standard LaTeX document format
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite} % Divine intervention help you if you need to use a different citation package.
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}


\usepackage{url}   % this allows us to cite URLs in the text
\usepackage{graphicx}   % allows for graphic to float when doing jou or doc style
\usepackage{verbatim}   % allows us to use \begin{comment} environment
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\title{Tables and apa6}
\author{Author Name}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Results}

\section{General Discussion}

There should be a marker here . 
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
 & 5 &  \\
   & 5 &  \\
   & 5 &  \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can confirm that this doesn't work.  It's puzzling that this question didn't receive more attention since this is a problem that pretty much every user of the apa6 should encounter.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same question and found that using the class option `floatsintext` in documentclass solves the problem.

Instead of `\documentclass[man]{apa6}` write it as `\documentclass[man, floatsintext]{apa6}`

It should look something like this:

```
\documentclass[man, floatsintext]{apa6} % man for manuscript format, jou for journal format, doc for standard LaTeX document format
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite} % Divine intervention help you if you need to use a different citation package.
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}


\usepackage{url}   % this allows us to cite URLs in the text
\usepackage{graphicx}   % allows for graphic to float when doing jou or doc style
\usepackage{verbatim}   % allows us to use \begin{comment} environment
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\title{Tables and apa6}
\author{Author Name}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Results}

\section{General Discussion}

There should be a marker here . 
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
 & 5 &  \\
   & 5 &  \\
   & 5 &  \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Markers like "Figure x about here" are not required by APA. So this is the expected behavior. For the 5th edition in a guide this is specifically mentioned: "There’s no need to say "Insert Table or Figure about here"." (Cash, 2009, p. 2)

And I assume this has not changed for APA 6th edition (at least I cannot find anything in the book that is related to it) and is probably still valid for APA 7th edition.

If you still want it, just create your own apa6.cls file (removing the `nomarkers` option) and put it in your working directory.

Cash, T. F. (2009). Caveats in the proficient preparation of an APA-style research manuscript for publication. Body Image, 6(1), 1–6. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.bodyim.2008.10.003